# How does sequelize model.update() optimises its writes?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sql-update

I am someone, who is very much interested understanding update operation in sequelize `model.update()`.

Suppose my table is with only one entry: ( assume 'id' is unique, sorted, index )

| id | fname | sname | email | dob | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | old_fname | old_sname | old_email | old_dob | old_phone_no |

I have gone through [sequelize's official website](https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/querying/update/), [sequelize core update method](https://sequelize.org/api/v7/classes/_sequelize_core.index.model#update) and also in the github [implementation of the sequelize-model.update() method](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/79111f0/packages/core/src/model.d.ts#L2769) . None of these descriptions and comments could answer my questions.

```
const dataToUpdate = {
    fname: new_fname,
    sname: old_sname, // Assume, I added it by mistake, same as old value
    email: old_email, // Assume, I added it by mistake, same as old value
    dob: new_dob,
};

const options = { where : { id : 1 } } ;

sequelize.model.update(dataToUpdate, options);
```

If this dataToUpdate, would be on Document-based database, then we would have simply overridden entire JSON object([assuming it is stored in JSON like DynamoDB](https://www.scylladb.com/learn/dynamodb/introduction-to-dynamodb/#:%7E:text=Amazon%20DynamoDB%20Data%20Modeling,be%20very%20different%20from%20others.)). **Only one write operation.**(of course, the input format would be different, but, in any format, based on 'id' field, there will be single write operation).

But, I am using row-order `postgres` database with `sequelize`.

0. In this case, how many write operations will be there internally in the database ?
   **Four operations ?**  or just **Two Operations ?**
   Will `sname` and `email` be overridden, even tough the values are same for those two columns. Or just **one operation** (first internally `get()` will occur, then old data will be merged with new data, and then old row will be over-written all at once. So total, one read + one write ) ?
1. How is `sequelize.model.update()` is implemented for `postgres` ? I would like to know, if someone can explain me, or may be redirect me to some educational, informative resources which can answer these kind of stupid doubts !

Thanks in advance.

Update:

Upon asking chat-gpt, I got this:

The number of actual database write operations can depend on the underlying implementation details of the database and the ORM (Sequelize in this case). Generally, it's common for an update operation to involve just one write operation. The database engine will handle the update efficiently.

Comment: This is a complex topic. If you are really interested search on "PostgreSQL MVC" and "PostgreSQL HOT" and "PostgreSQL WAL" and also "write amplification"

Comment: @RichardHuxton , yeah I am really interested !!! Thanks, I will go through these topics over the weekend. FUN TIME begins !!!

Comment: as for `sequelize.model.update()` - it will be on UPDATE query for any RDMS that is supported in Sequelize. You can look at generated SQL to check that if you turn the logging on

Comment: @Anatoly , I know that `logging: true` flag we can provide when we create sequelize instance. But that doesn't explain what happens at database levels